# memberOf attribute does not exist when user is in a group (dirsrv, CentOS6.2)

Tags: ldap, centos

I have a problem adding user in a group using dirsrv, CentOS6.2.
Default schema, have user *jmarsden* in "People" and created a group into "Groups".

Tried to use any types of the group: *groupOfNames*, *groupOfUniqueNames*, *posixgroup*. Member (uniqueMember or memberUid) is successfully added as attribute.

```
 member=uid=jmarsden,ou=People,dc=mymy,dc=localdomain
```

But when I fetch operational attributes using Apache Directory Studio there is not *memberOf* attribute for user *jmarsden*. Search with filter *"memberOf=cn=M*"* does not work either.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

memberOf is an attribute that is most often associated with Active Directory.
Many LDAP implementation do not use an attribute on the user to represent which group the users are a member of.

Which LDAP implementation are your using?

Comment: I am using CentOS Directory Service. Is there any analog for memberOf attribute that can be used in search with filter? It is strange that I do not see any attributes related to the group when I fetch operational attributes

Comment: I personally do not know. Never heard of CentOS Directory Service. What are you trying to do ? Why not search the groups for the DN of the user? That ALWAYS works. (Unless there are nested groups).

Comment: Actually OpenLDAP also can handle _memberOf_ when module **memberof** is configured, it's not only Microsoft AD feature.